# Any way to use DIVs to achieve horizontal alignment of TDs for dynamic content?

Tags: html, css, alignment, css-tables

Yet again looking at one of my old table ridden webpages I need to redesign.

Is there any way to achieve same flexibility using divs and modern CSS?

Most basic problem I am having: table of 2 rows, 2 columns. First column is label, second is a text input field.

```
<table style='width:100%; white-space: nowrap'>
<tr>
    <td style='width:1%'><label>Dynamic Long Text</label></td>
    <td style='width:99%' ><input style='width:100%' type="text"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><label>Dyn. Shrt. Text</label></td>
    <td><input style='width:100%' type="text"/></td>
</tr>
```

Labels are plugged in from a language dictionary, in some languages first label will be wider, in some second one. Max possible space should be allocated to the text fields, but text fields should be horizontally aligned on both sides. Labels should be aligned on left only.

How do I get the same effect with `DIV`s and CSS?

This is a simplified case of my problem, but the actual form is quite cluttered with controls, and it cannot be split up into multiple pages.

In my old design that second column usually contains nested single row tables rather then a single control - very messy code, but it's all resulting from the same problem:

1. I need the labels to be aligned. (usually only the leftmost labels on every row should be aligned)
2. Labels get dynamic content of unknown width, depending on language selected by user.
3. I need to squeeze every pixel to fit all the controls on the form.

(yes it's cluttered design, but client insists that all fields are necessary on the same screen)

In the old `<table>` version I just rely on `td`s to align themselves, and to prevent extremely lengthy text resources from breaking the layout, I have `maxwidth` defined on everything. But under those `maxwidth`s, controls should be taking advantage of all space available, with input fields stretching to get every pixel that the dynamic labels haven't eaten. The language differences can be quite extreme too - a label might get `40px` longer in some, while another on the same row gets shorter.

edit:

To give an example of the problems I am running into that results in having nested tables:

On one row in the same section I need to have a label/textval pair, followed by a button and another label/textval pair.

Then a second row that has just 4 labl/text val pairs.

Then a third that has a label and then 4 checkboxes each with their own labels.

Then a label with only very long field ...

So, usually those first starting labels on each row need to be aligned (so I have them all in first table-cell, but then the rest of the controls per row aren't uniform, and contained in their own single row tables.

And the form has 20-40 rows like depending on which sections are expanded/hidden - and because we are asked to display all of this on a single screen (we aren't even allowed vertical scrolling. If user expands too many sections to fit, height-wise, we have to automatically collapse other sections), our design meetings are almost literally counting where we can shave pixels to fit stuff in.

Comment: I think this flies in the face of responsive design and mobile apps.  Media queries are the way to handle this now.  Think bootstrap and grid.  Discard those table layouts.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what your goal is, are you trying to achieve the same results that this table would achieve, but instead of using an HTML table you would like to do this using CSS?

Comment: It sounds like you need to display tabular data which you should be using a table. You could set the display of div to table-cell and have the same affect but again, if you want to display tabular data, why not use a table

Comment: @duffymo - Discarding the table layout is exactly what I am trying to do now. My problem is how to do so while satisfying the above 3 requirements. In this case, this web application is for use on internal company network, desktop data-entry. Mobile devices are to be handled by other services.

Comment: @mgrenier and Huangism yes, exactly. Right now my form has an average of 3 nested tables on every row. It works perfectly - but every web-design page I see, keeps telling me I shouldn't be doing it. Web programming isn't my main skill set, so I was just wondering if there is a more graceful way to do it

Comment: LIke I said - bootstrap and grid.  You shouldn't do this in isolation.  You should talk to the mobile device folks to make sure you can satisfy both with a single, responsive, mobile first UI.  Your company will thank you.  This is your chance to add a new skill to your toolbox.

Comment: this might be a starting point for you to mess around with ...http://jsfiddle.net/1ngdhn9k/

Comment: @user1250290 this is probably a bigger issue than you think. If coding for the web is not your profession. I suggest you consult a professional and have them do it for you. It is very hard to explain what needs to happen specially when you are not a web developer. The amount of work involved could proven too much for you + you will probbaly have bugs that you need to deal with

Comment: There are people that argue that this is a kind of tabular data (description/label and associated input field, multiple times), so that semantically a table would not actually be a wrong choice. The argument that one might not want to display this as a table on smaller screens is valid – but all modern browsers should support breaking such a table up into two “rows” each for description and input field by making the table cells `display:block` …

Comment: I would agree with both Huangism that this may be a larger undertaking that you are thinking it will be, and CBroe that tables are not necessarily the wrong way.  If you aren't to familiar with web design and CSS specifically then tables may be the easiest way to accomplish it.  And if it ain't broke...

Answer (score 1):

This shouldn't be too difficult to achieve as long as your tables aren't too complicated.

Here is an example of a solution for your most basic problem:

```
<div class="table">
<div class="col">
    <div class="row">row 1</div>
    <div class="row">row 1 row 1</div>
</div>
<div class="col">
    <div class="row">
        <input type="text" value="input" />
    </div>
    <div class="row">something</div>
</div>
</div>


.table, .col {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b44wjkj2/1/

Comment: That looks almost exactly like what I need.

It satisfies the alignment requirement, but assuming "table" div is set to 100% width, how do I get the second column div to expand to take up all available width? Like for example if i want that input to be as wide as possible?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there isn't a way to do that without javascript or using `display: table` and `display: table-cell` for some of you elements - not sure how different that is from using an actual table... You can look at this question which has a similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27573737/change-proportions-of-3-columned-display-table-table-cell/27573902#27573902

Comment: Just realized your solution does pretty much the same thing as the one I linked to - setting one column to 1% width and the other to 99% (the link has 3 columns so it's a little different), but you'd have to look into if using `display: table` is better practice than using an actual table, because I'm not really sure about that